# How not to put data in a map when a whole row is empty

Tags: java, sql-server, database, spring

I am trying to make a Map out of a List and facing some difficulties.
I have a List called "surveyAnsList" and from that list I would like to get only "type C" data and put those data in maps called "mapC" and put those maps in a JSONArray. **And when I do this, I don't want some empty "answerValue" to be put in the maps.**

My DB is like
[image]

**The empty AnswerValue in 'CompanyRegistrationNumber 987-65-43210, RowNum 2, ColNum 3' row should be included in the map, but the empty AnswerValues in 'CompanyRegistrationNumber 123-45-56778, RowNum 2, ColNum 2-6' row should NOT be included in the map because the whole AnswerValues for RowNum 2 are empty.**

The code I've tried is like this.

```
    for(int i=0; i<surveyAnsList.size(); i++){
            String answerType = surveyAnsList.get(i).getAnswerType();

            String rowNum = surveyAnsList.get(i).getRowNum();
            String colNum = surveyAnsList.get(i).getColNum();
            String order1 = surveyAnsList.get(i).getQuestionOrder1();
            String order2 = surveyAnsList.get(i).getQuestionOrder2();
            String answerValue = surveyAnsList.get(i).getAnswerValue();
            String companyRegistrationNumber = surveyAnsList.get(i).getCompanyRegistrationNumber();
            String companyName = surveyAnsList.get(i).getCompanyName();

            String[] answerTypeArr = answerType.split("\\|");
            String typeCAnswer = "";
            String newValue = "";


            String cNum = "";

            Map<String, Object> mapC = new HashMap<>();
            mapC.put("questionOrder1", order1);
            mapC.put("questionOrder2", order2);
            mapC.put("rowNum", rowNum);
            mapC.put("colNum", colNum);
            mapC.put("answerValue", answerValue);
            mapC.put("companyRegistrationNumber", companyRegistrationNumber);
            mapC.put("companyName", companyName);

            if(!jsonArrayC_TN3.contains(mapC)){
                jsonArrayC_TN3.add(mapC);
            }
        }
```

Of course the map is including every empty AnswerValue in this case. How to I achieve what I want?

Comment: You can collect the rows for each CompanyRegistrationNumber in a list and add them to your map as soon there is another number or no next row. Before adding the values to your list you can iterate over the CurrentComapanyRegistrationNumberList and check if there is at least one answer present.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the follow code could help you

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> nameMap = new HashMap<>(); // tore the name and index
        Set<String> values = new HashSet<>();  // judge if the whole AnswerValues is null
        for(int i=0; i<surveyAnsList.size(); i++){
            String answerType = surveyAnsList.get(i).getAnswerType();

            String rowNum = surveyAnsList.get(i).getRowNum();
            String colNum = surveyAnsList.get(i).getColNum();
            String order1 = surveyAnsList.get(i).getQuestionOrder1();
            String order2 = surveyAnsList.get(i).getQuestionOrder2();
            String answerValue = surveyAnsList.get(i).getAnswerValue();
            String companyRegistrationNumber = surveyAnsList.get(i).getCompanyRegistrationNumber();
            String companyName = surveyAnsList.get(i).getCompanyName();

            if (!nameMap.keySet().contains(companyRegistrationNumber)) {
                if(values.size() == 0 && i != 0){ // remove the null value map, stored in jsonArrayC_TN3
                    nameMap.get("companyRegistrationNumber").forEach(jsonArrayC_TN3::remove);
                }
                nameMap.put(companyRegistrationNumber, new ArrayList<>());
                values = new HashSet<>();
            }
            if (answerValue != null) {
                values.add(answerValue);
                nameMap.get("companyRegistrationNumber").add(jsonArrayC_TN3.size());
            }

            String[] answerTypeArr = answerType.split("\\|");
            String typeCAnswer = "";
            String newValue = "";


            String cNum = "";

            Map<String, Object> mapC = new HashMap<>();
            mapC.put("questionOrder1", order1);
            mapC.put("questionOrder2", order2);
            mapC.put("rowNum", rowNum);
            mapC.put("colNum", colNum);
            mapC.put("answerValue", answerValue);
            mapC.put("companyRegistrationNumber", companyRegistrationNumber);
            mapC.put("companyName", companyName);

            if(!jsonArrayC_TN3.contains(mapC)){
                jsonArrayC_TN3.add(mapC);
            }
        }
```